# GROUP_CONCAT with multiple LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have problem with GROUP_CONCAT with multiple LEFT JOINs.

I have main table `connectors` which holds data, but because mysql table cannot hold array I stored them in different tables `modules`, `subassemblies` and every element from array has its own line. My query works OK when those arrays are same length, but when i fetch 3 rows from modules table but only one from `subassemblies` table, than i get wrong result.

example result:

```
id     modulepath     subassemblypath
1      mp1|mp2|mp3    sp1|sp1|sp1              my result
1      mp1|mp2|mp3    sp1                      expected result
```

connectors table:

```
id     data
1      lorem
2      ipsum
3      data
```

modules table:

```
id     cid     modulepath
28     1       mp1
29     1       mp2
36     1       mp3
56     3       mp4
85     2       mp5
```

subassemblies table:

```
id     cid     subassemblypath
26     1       sp1
31     2       sp2
48     2       sp3
56     3       sp4
```

my query:

```
SELECT 
c.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(m.modulepath SEPARATOR "|") AS modulepath, 
GROUP_CONCAT(s.subassemblypath SEPARATOR "|") AS subassemblypath 
FROM connectors c 
LEFT JOIN modules m ON m.cid = c.id 
LEFT JOIN subassemblies s ON s.cid = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Please show the input data

Comment: Share exact table structures with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split the query into the two and then perform the join

```
SELECT c.*, t2.modulepath, t1.subassemblypath 
FROM connectors c 
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   s.cid,
   GROUP_CONCAT(s.subassemblypath SEPARATOR "|") AS subassemblypath 
  FROM subassemblies s
  GROUP BY s.cid
) t1 ON c.id = t1.cid
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
   m.cid,
   GROUP_CONCAT(m.modulepath SEPARATOR "|") AS modulepath
  FROM modules m
  GROUP BY m.cid
) t2 ON c.id = t2.cid
```

Comment: I am trying your code but it gives me syntax error which i am trying to find and fix. But thanks for this push in right direction. I appreciate it.

Comment: No need, i already got it working. Thank you very much for help :) Mistake was on my side because i have to use it inline and i made mistake when deleting linebreaks.